# 'grunt' command doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, configuration, gruntjs

I'm following the grunt [getting started guide](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) for my new app, but I'm having some trouble.

This is my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {,
      build: {
        src: 'js/*.js',
        dest: 'build/*.min.js'
      }
    }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);

};
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "N/A",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.7"
  }
}
```

I have the grunt-cli package installed and I've run npm install to get a local version of grunt and the contrib libraries.

But when I run either `grunt` or `grunt uglify` nothing happens.

```
$ grunt
$ grunt uglify
$
```

Any idea what I have missed or what could cause this behaviour?

EDIT: I just installed mocha too and I get the same issue with that: no output. Maybe there is a problem with my node or npm installation

Comment: I'm guessing /js/ is not empty, right?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv that is correct

Comment: Try with the `--verbose` option to see what you get. Also, run `grunt --version` just to make sure you get a proper grunt execution (should just print the Grunt cli version number).

Comment: @jakerella I get no output from running `grunt --version` or `grunt --verbose`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So it looks like this was an environment setup issue. I had an ubuntu package called node installed as well as nodejs which was preventing the packages installed through npm from working. Running the following command fixed the issue.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node
```

Comment: Thanks for discovering this solution! Just hit this very same issue.  Rather hard to debug something that doesn't even throw an error...

Comment: I also had to to this:
    sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. Grunt was not responding. No output was being displayed.
Removing node and installing nodejs-legacy worked for me.

Removing node by:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node
```

and installing legacy by:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that ubuntu installations come with a package called "node" that is not "node js". The included node is often not needed and so can be safely removed. You shouldn't need to install the nodejs-legacy though. `sudo apt-get install nodejs` should work!