# Grunt not outputting, returning error

Tags: node.js, maven, gruntjs, output, stdout

I run a website which uses Grunt to collect all of my assets into a compiled bundle (translating Less into CSS, translating TS into JS, running tests, etc.). I recently moved to a new computer. Although my source files (including package.json, Gruntfile, pom.xml, etc.) are store in the project's Git repo, I needed to redo `npm install`, etc. All of this is automated through Maven, using `grunt-maven-plugin`, with the `npm-compile` and `grunt-compile` goals.

I installed grunt with `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`, then ran `mvn package` to set up my project. It ran into a few issues installing all my node dependencies, but ultimately got past that. Then it just printed this:

```
[INFO] --- grunt-maven-plugin:1.4.1:grunt (grunt-build) @ Website ---
[INFO] OS Name: Linux
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.103s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue May 26 22:53:58 PDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/304M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal pl.allegro:grunt-maven-plugin:1.4.1:grunt (grunt-build) on project Website: Unable to execute mojo: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

Okay, so...Grunt's returning a value of 1. Certainly strange -- I'd never heard of it before.

Long story short, when I started messing with it, I realized grunt wasn't printing anything:

```
[user@computer] ~ $ grunt
[user@computer] ~ $ grunt --version
[user@computer] ~ $ grunt --help
[user@computer] ~ $
```

Grunt's definitely installed. `whereis grunt` returns `/usr/local/bin/grunt`, which is a symlink to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt`, which seems to be the standard install directory for global packages.

I have no idea where to go from here. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling grunt (both by doing `npm uninstall -g grunt-cli` and by manually deleting the node_modules folder [it's all that was in it]). And yes, the `grunt` package is installed locally in the project. Please help.

I'm running Linux Mint 17.3 Rebecca, and I confirmed I'm running the latest versions of npm, grunt, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937313/grunt-command-doesnt-do-anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `node` package, that's not `nodejs` and cause a conflict most of the time.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node
```

Comment: Thanks. That's...kind of stupid, but I guess there's probably some reasoning and/or history there. Anyway, yeah, I just purged that and then did a `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` to make sure everything else played nicely, and that seemed to do it. Thanks again!